# How to realize the interaction inside and outside a docker container

Tags: docker, ssh

For example, when I'm build a docker image based on debian, I want to install ssh service and then set the ssh user and password on a Dockerfile. If I don't want to do it after I run it although it can make sense. Thanks for your help!

```html
...

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  # install ssh service
  apt-get install openssh-server -y && \
  mkdir -p /var/run/sshd && \
  useradd sshuser && \
  passwd sshuser && \

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "&"]

...
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you're trying to do? Do you want to create a docker image with sshd installed and have a predefinied password?

Comment: @ffledgling Yes，through this I can use the **sshuser** and it's password to login outside the container.

Answer (score 1):

Change your docker file to this to do exactly what you were trying to do originally.

```
...

RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  # install ssh service
  apt-get install openssh-server -y && \
  mkdir -p /var/run/sshd
RUN useradd sshuser -m -p $(openssl passwd $PASS)

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D", "&"]

...
```

Although be aware that this means the password you generate is forever encoded in your docker file and visible to anyone who views it. You can give an encrypted SHA instead of a plaintext password, but that's still not a great idea.

See [man useradd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/useradd) for more information.

---

As a suggestion/aside, a better way of doing this in the docker world is to not install `sshd` inside the container at all. Instead use:

```
$ docker exec -i -t <name of the running container> -- /bin/bash
```

This assumes the container is already running. Docker exec does not need any sort of username or password to access the container.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I can set my **sshuser** password through the variable when I run it even the ssh user's account.

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion and it didn't work. I go into the running container to set another user using
``
useradd test -m -p mypassword
``
and find it didn't work either.

Comment: @wizChen you'll need to be a little more clear about what you're trying to do and what you want. What do you mean *it didn't work*? What are the commands you tried and what are the error messages you got? Can you pastebin them/add them to your question?

Comment: I' sorry = =. I've tried your suggestion. I run the command **ssh sshuser@localhost -p 10081** (I've ever exposed this port 10081 on my host to the container's port 22), and when I input the password it prompted me that I have the wrong password.
So I ran the "exec" command to go into the running container and the same problem happened.
Then I make a test: I ran the command **useradd test -m -p 123456** and I still can't login the **test** user through ssh.
So I doubt that the command **useradd sshuser -m -p password** may not the right one to meet my need.

Comment: @wizChen, two things. 1) My command to set the password was incorrect, you need to give the encrypted password and not the raw password, see my edit to the question. 2) `docker exec` still works, it will give a shell into the container so you don't need to SSH into it at all.

Comment: Ok, I'll try later. Thanks for your patient answering :)